# Is there a way to open the "Connect to Server" without opening Nautilus first?

Tags: nautilus

Currently the only way I know of to open the "Connect to server" dialog box is to open up Nautilus first.

While this isn't that complex a task, it still requires using the mouse, at a minimum:

1. Launch Nautilus (Super + 1)
2. Move mouse to top left to "File"
3. Select "Connect to server"

It would be great if I could simply click the Super button to go into the dash and type "connect to" and click enter.

Comment: You can replace steps 2 and 3 with **Alt+F**, **S** if you want to avoid using the mouse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My suggestion is that you add it to your Home icon on the launcher, like this:

[image]

**«That's insanely cool!», you say, «But how do I do that?».** Well, you just copy and paste the desktop file I made for you into an empty file and copy that to your ~/.local/share/applications/ folder. Name the file "nautilus.desktop". You need to log out and back in afterwards. Here goes:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Files
Comment=Access and organize files
Exec=nautilus %U
Icon=system-file-manager
Terminal=false
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
OnlyShowIn=GNOME;Unity;
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Utility;Core;
MimeType=inode/directory;application/x-gnome-saved-search;
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Bugzilla=GNOME
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Product=nautilus
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Component=general
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Version=3.2.1
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=nautilus
X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=Connect;Videos;Documents;Music;Pictures;Downloads
[Connect Shortcut Group]
Name=Connect
Exec=nautilus-connect-server
TargetEnvironment=Unity
```

[Videos Shortcut Group]
Name=Videos
Exec=nautilus Videos
TargetEnvironment=Unity

[Documents Shortcut Group]
Name=Documents
Exec=nautilus Documents
TargetEnvironment=Unity

[Music Shortcut Group]
Name=Music
Exec=nautilus Music
TargetEnvironment=Unity

[Pictures Shortcut Group]
Name=Pictures
Exec=nautilus Pictures
TargetEnvironment=Unity

[Downloads Shortcut Group]
Name=Downloads
Exec=nautilus Downloads
TargetEnvironment=Unity
.

Comment: does this keep my bookmarks?

Comment: Yes, I think the bookmarks are added at runtime (dynamic quicklists) whereas these are added to the .desktop file to make them accessible even when Nautilus is not running.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is a way to open the “Connect to Server” without opening Nautilus first.

Run `nautilus-connect-server`. It will appear as a Nautilus icon in your launcher, so you can right click it and "Keep in launcher" to make it stay there.

Answer (score 2):

A slightly faster option is to click **File ▸ Connect to Server...** while on the desktop. This works because the desktop is provided by Nautilus.

Of course, this is still an inconvenience when you already have other windows open.

Related bug reports:

- [nautilus desktop: Unity menu and alt key navigation](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/790687)

Comment: I think this only works in Ubuntu 11.04.

Comment: No, it works in 11.10 as well, but the solution is based on a bug. The desktop shouldn't display menus for Nautilus.

Comment: @Jo-ErlendSchinstad That's disappointing to hear. Do you have a link to the bug report?